# Помогите трансформировать фигуру CSS JS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите пожалуйста трансформировать прямоугольник в это

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/X9QeRStKopUQ-g
Онлайн редакторами пытался...

Прямоугольник это просто div, реализовать через css, js,
при наведении через hover

Comment: Прямоугольник у вас что? Картинка, html-элемент, svg-элемент?

Comment: html Элемент  =)

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oNwBMrV вот таке можно

Answer (score 4):

```css
.transformation{
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;  
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.transformation:hover{
  transform: perspective(100px) translateZ(-40px);
}
.transformation__item{
  background-color: #cda;
  width: 20%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0, black 5px, yellow 5px, yellow 10px);
  transition: inherit;
}
.transformation__item--left{
  transform-origin: right center;  
}
.transformation:hover .transformation__item--left{
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(10deg);
}
.transformation__item--center{
  width: 60%;
}
.transformation__item--right{
  transform-origin: left center;  
}
.transformation:hover .transformation__item--right{
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="transformation">
  <div class="transformation__item transformation__item--left"></div>
  <div class="transformation__item transformation__item--center"></div>
  <div class="transformation__item transformation__item--right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не могу реализовать =(

Comment: Добавьте код ваших попыток и уточните желаемый результат в вопросе. Сделал трансформацию по наведению в ответе.

Comment: Мощно! И не понятно))) Можете пояснить в комментариях что происходит?

Comment: @Leonid , запросто!  При наведении блок целиком отдаляется на 40px вглубь (т.е. по оси Z). Края блока заворачиваются на 10 градусов к наблюдателю. Вот и получается такой эффект, как в условии вопроса.

Comment: Я имел в виду в комментариях к коду)) Не суть. А не отрываются они друг от друга из-за display: flex родителя? И почему все вместе не смещается влево?

Comment: теперь пытаюсь реализовать когда 3 divа  одинакового размера

Comment: @Leonid , не отрываются друг от друга из-за `display: flex` родителя и из-за того, что трансформация по оси z применяется к обёртке, а не к каждой части по отдельности. По поводу смещения влево не понял. Почему должны смещаться?

Comment: @franklin , если что-то не получается, добавьте код своих попыток в вопрос. В противном случае помочь вам больше нечем